# How do you determine an image height and width for webkit Chrome and Safari browsers?

Tags: javascript

guys! Here goes my first question. I've gathered up this small script that will center elements horizontally and vertically at the same time with just the use of a class. Here goes

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.vAlign = function() {
return this.each(function(i){
var h = $(this).height();
var oh = $(this).outerHeight();
var mt = (h + (oh - h)) / 2;
$(this).css("margin-top", "-" + mt + "px");
$(this).css("top", "50%");
$(this).css("position", "absolute");
});
};
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
$.fn.hAlign = function() {
return this.each(function(i){
var w = $(this).width();
var ow = $(this).outerWidth();
var ml = (w + (ow - w)) / 2;
$(this).css("margin-left", "-" + ml + "px");
$(this).css("left", "50%");
$(this).css("position", "absolute");
});
};
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".vAlign").vAlign();
$(".hAlign").hAlign();
});
```

I have succesfully centered ANYTHING relative to any container (that has  "position:relative") using the classes "vAlign" or "hAlign" or both, EXCEPT for the images (`<img/>`) and ONLY on the webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari). This means that, in this example;

```
<div class="hAlign vAlign">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu dui eget nulla condimentum gravida. Vivamus erat leo, ultricies quis, gravida a, fringilla eu, urna. Pellentesque a mauris ac nisl semper egestas. Pellentesque ut elit in pede mattis gravida. Donec ac lectus a nisi suscipit placerat. Maecenas quis ipsum. Pellentesque mattis tellus. Suspendisse sollicitudin accumsan tortor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed metus. Quisque et leo at erat rutrum lobortis. In tempus lectus eget ligula convallis tristique.
</div>

<img class="hAlign vAlign" src="http://rlv.zcache.es/cara_de_lol_etiquetas_redondas-p217382006305499446envb3_400.jpg" alt="lol" />
```

The div will be centered both horizontal and vertically on any browser, as will any other tag that isn't "img" (even "input", or "button"). However, the img will not center on webkit browsers.

I've looked everywhere but, either I didn't find the answer, or I didn't understand it. I have basically no idea of JS, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you are trying to get the dimension of the image before it was downloaded. Try `$(window).bind('load', function(){...});`

Comment: Excellent! Nothing more to say! Thank you SO much!!

Comment: @jantimon Maybe you should post that as an answer to this question, then. :)

Answer (score 0):

To measure the width and height of an image you have to be sure that your image was downloaded properly.

There are two solutions:

1. You could wait for all files to be downloaded by waiting for the window load event: 
   [window.onload vs document.ready jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778070/window-onload-vs-document-ready-jquery)

   ```
   $(window).on('load', function(){
     ...
   });
   ```
2. There is the "imagesLoaded" plugin which helps you to solve this issue. It does not require jQuery and allows to wait for a single or for multiple images to be load:
   http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/

   ```
   $.fn.vAlign = function(){
     this.imagesLoad().always(function(){
       ...
     });
     return this;
   };
   ```